# CiviCRM installation on Ubuntu via package manager

Tags: drupal, installation

CiviCRM for Drupal 7 is [packaged](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=civicrm) for Ubuntu in the [Universe repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

However, the [CiviCRM installation documentation](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7) does not list installation via  the operating system's package manager (e.g. [`apt-get`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)) as a recommended installation route.

Is that just because this installation route hasn't been documented yet, or is it because this installation route causes problems that are avoided by following the recommended route? If the latter, which problems are caused by using the OS's package manager?

*I do not currently have an Ubuntu system available on which to evaluate the stability/bugginess of those packages myself, hence my asking here.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very new work - CiviCRM was recently packaged for Debian by a Debian developer.  It's in Debian sid now, and Ubuntu seems to be pulling it in from there.

In short - it's not documented yet because it's new, and it's hard to say if there are issues with this approach because not many folks are using it yet.